# Proc freq: frequencies over the total

Tags: sas

is there a way to divide the "count" from proc freq by the total number of rows of a data set?
My proc freq is the following:

> proc freq noprint data=mydata;
> by place;
> table weight  / out=freqs;
> run;

I don't want % on classes by over the total.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a by-group. This will create individaul calculations per group. Instead, create a table of `weight*place`.

```
proc freq noprint data=mydata;
    table weight*place / out=freqs;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Stu. The problem is that I have not only "place" but also "grade", "social_status", "conditionA", "conditionB", "conditionC". Weight should be stratified by all the other "by" variables I mentioned here.